# Optionmenu in tkinter does not work properly when ttkthemes is used

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, ttk, ttkwidgets

Is there a solution to this , the `Optionmenu` with `ttkthemes` seems to not give the normal functioning of the Optionmenu.
Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font
from tkinter.font import Font
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from tkcalendar import Calendar
import mysql.connector as mysql
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import themed_tk as tktheme
#root=Tk()

root = tktheme.ThemedTk()
root.get_themes()
root.set_theme('vista')
root.title('Patient Information')
font_text = Font(family='helvetica',size='11')
font_button = Font(size='10')

gen = ['Male','Female']
bl_gr = ['A+','A-','B+','B-','O+','O-','AB+','AB-']
cov = ['Yes','No','N/A']

def database():
    nme = name.get()
    p_h = ph.get()
    eid = e_id.get()
    ema_id = em_id.get()
    nat = nation.get()
    emer = emerg.get()
    gend = g.get()
    bloo = b.get()
    covi = co.get()
    dat = cal.selection_get()

    if nme=="" or p_h=="" or eid=="" or ema_id=="" or nat=="" or emer=="" or gend=="" or bloo=="" or covi=="" or dat=="":
        messagebox.showinfo('Fill all','All fields are necessary')
    else:
        con = mysql.connect(host='localhost', user='username', password='*****', database='DB')
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute("Insert into PATIENTS VALUES ('"+nme+"','"+p_h+"','"+eid+"','"+ema_id+"','"+gend+"','"+str(dat)+"','"+nat+"','"+str(bloo)+"','"+str(covi)+"','"+emer+"')")
        c.execute('commit')
        con.close()
        messagebox.showinfo('Success','All values have been entered to the database')
        e1.delete(0, END)
        e2.delete(0, END)
        e3.delete(0, END)
        e4.delete(0, END)
        e5.delete(0, END)
        e6.delete(0, END)

def datepicker():
    global cal
    global a
    def date():
        global cal
        a = cal.selection_get()

    top = Toplevel(root)
    top.title('Choose Date')
    cal = Calendar(top,font="Arial 14", selectmode='day', year=2006, month=1, day=1)
    cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    Button(top, text="OK", command=top.destroy,font=font_text).pack(fill='both')

def newtop():
    global new
    global img
    global img_prof
    new = Toplevel(root)
    mainfiledir = Image.open('/HSPTL/ID Card.png')
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(mainfiledir)
    img_label = Label(new, image=img)
    img_label.grid(row=1, column=2)
    dir = Image.open(path)
    dir = dir.resize((150, 150), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img_prof = ImageTk.PhotoImage(dir)
    img_label = Label(new, image=img_prof)
    img_label.place(x=500, y=150)
    lo1 = Label(new, text=e1.get(), bg='white', font=font_text).place(x=330, y=127)
    lo2 = Label(new, text=e2.get(), bg='white', font=font_text).place(x=345, y=155)
    lo3 = Label(new, text=e3.get(), bg='white', font=font_text).place(x=315, y=183)
    lo4 = Label(new, text=g.get(), bg='white', font=font_text).place(x=165, y=227)
    lo5 = Label(new, text=b.get(), bg='white', font=font_text).place(x=220, y=257)
    lo6 = Label(new, text=cal.selection_get(), bg='white', font=font_text).place(x=220, y=288)

def imgpath():
    global path
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/Donwloads',title='Select Photo',filetypes=(('PNG files','*.png'),
                                                                                              ('JPEG files','*.jpg')))

def popup():
    selection = messagebox.askyesno('Exit','Are you sure you want to exit?')
    if selection == 1:
        root.destroy()
    else:
        Label(root,text="")

def reset():
    select = messagebox.askyesno('Reset', 'Are you sure you want to Reset?')
    if select == 1:
        e1.delete(0, END)
        e2.delete(0, END)
        e3.delete(0, END)
        e4.delete(0, END)
        e5.delete(0, END)
        e6.delete(0, END)
    else:
        Label(root, text="")


l1 = ttk.Label(root,text='Name',font=font_text)
l2 = ttk.Label(root,text='Phone Number',font=font_text)
l3 = ttk.Label(root,text='Emirates ID',font=font_text)
l4 = ttk.Label(root,text='Email Address',font=font_text)
l5 = ttk.Label(root,text='Gender',font=font_text)
l6 = ttk.Label(root,text='Date Of Birth',font=font_text)
l7 = ttk.Label(root,text='Nationality',font=font_text)
l8 = ttk.Label(root,text='Blood Group',font=font_text)
l9 = ttk.Label(root,text='Test for COVID-19',font=font_text)
l10 = ttk.Label(root,text='Emergency Contact Number',font=font_text)
l11 = ttk.Label(root,text='Select Photo',font=font_text)

name = StringVar()
ph = StringVar()
e_id = StringVar()
em_id = StringVar()
nation = StringVar()
emerg = StringVar()


e1 = ttk.Entry(root,textvariable=name)
e2 = ttk.Entry(root,textvariable=ph)
e3 = ttk.Entry(root,textvariable=e_id)
e4 = ttk.Entry(root,textvariable=em_id)
e5 = ttk.Entry(root,textvariable=nation)
e6 = ttk.Entry(root,textvariable=emerg)

b_ch = ttk.Button(root,text='Select Image',command=imgpath)
b_id = ttk.Button(root,text='Make ID Card',command=newtop)
b_db = ttk.Button(root,text='Enter Database',command=database)
b_ex = ttk.Button(root,text='Exit',command=popup)
b_re = ttk.Button(root,text='Reset',command=reset)
b_dt = ttk.Button(root,text='Choose Date',command=datepicker)

g = StringVar()
g.set('Choose Gender')
opt_g = OptionMenu(root,g,*gen)

b = StringVar()
b.set('Choose group')
opt_blo = OptionMenu(root,b,*bl_gr)

co = StringVar()
co.set('Choose result')
opt_cov = OptionMenu(root,co,*cov)


l1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10)
l2.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10)
l3.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10)
l4.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=10)
l5.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=10)
l6.grid(row=5,column=0,padx=10)
l7.grid(row=6,column=0,padx=10)
l8.grid(row=7,column=0,padx=10)
l9.grid(row=8,column=0,padx=10,pady=5)
l10.grid(row=9,column=0,padx=10)
l11.grid(row=10,column=0,padx=10)

e1.grid(row=0,column=1,pady=5,ipady=5,padx=5)
e2.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=5,ipady=5,padx=5)
e3.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=5,ipady=5,padx=5)
e4.grid(row=3,column=1,pady=5,ipady=5,padx=5)
e5.grid(row=6,column=1,pady=6,ipady=5,padx=5)
e6.grid(row=9,column=1,pady=5,ipady=5,padx=5)

b_ch.grid(row=10,column=1,sticky=E+W,pady=5,padx=5)
b_id.grid(row=11,column=0,sticky=E+W,padx=10,pady=5)
b_db.grid(row=11,column=1,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
b_ex.grid(row=12,column=1,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
b_re.grid(row=12,column=0,sticky=E+W,padx=10,pady=5)
b_dt.grid(row=5,column=1,sticky=E+W,padx=7,pady=5,ipadx=5)

opt_g.grid(row=4,column=1,ipadx=6,pady=3)
opt_blo.grid(row=7,column=1,padx=5,ipadx=10)
opt_cov.grid(row=8,column=1,ipadx=12,pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

**Without ttkthemes**

[image: Without ttkthemes]

**With ttkthemes**

[image: With ttkthemes]

Is it a problem in code or is it like that and has no fix?

Comment: Switching the widget set like that shouldn't lose a menu entry! Looks like a bug, probably in Tkinter (as there's technically no Tk function for creating a Ttk option menu; it's too trivial!)

Comment: I don't really understand what it is with the different behaviour with the Ttk widget you don't like. The optionmenu has slight differences in interface between Tk and Ttk, so that might be the problem.

Comment: The bug is the disappearance of the “`Male`” option.

Comment: any fixes or alternatives?